# How to apply one specific change to database after 'makemigrations' command?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I added a field to one of my models, but in the 'models' folder I have two other python files which have only View models from which I query views in my database. When I run the makemigrations command, the new migrations file that is created includes also adding these view models to my database as tables (which I don't want to). How can I ignore these changes, and only commit the one addition of a field to an actual table on the database.

I think I maybe have to delete the `migrations.CreateModel...` in the new migrations file and only keep the `migrations.addField...` , then run the 'migrate' command. I didn't proceed with this because I'm not sure and maybe it will mess up my database in some way.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: show you 'view' files because it shouldn't be trying to make models if they're not models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you make a model for database view you must add meta class managed = false and db_table like this:

```
class MyViewModel(models.Model):
    field: models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'database_view_name'
```

when you write this and run makemigrations a migration generated contains this model but when you run migrate this migration doesnt change anything on database.

you also can create view using migrations in python. see [migrations.RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) for more details